# Wrap a value in a function unless it's already a function

Tags: typescript, function, generics

I have this function in Javascript, and I want to write a type signature for it.

```
function wrapInFunction(value) {
  if (typeof value === 'function') {
    return value;
  } else {
    return () => value;
  }
}
```

It takes a thing that may or may not be a function and, if it's not a function, makes it into one in a trivial way. My first thought was to do this

```
function wrapInFunction<A extends Array<unknown>, B>(value: B | ((...a: A) => B)): (...a: A) => B {
  if (typeof value === 'function') {
    return value;
  } else {
    return () => value;
  }
}
```

To this, Typescript rightly pointed out that if `B & Function` is nonempty, then the first case is a type error

```
src/op.ts:360:5 - error TS2322: Type '((...a: A) => B) | (B & Function)' is not assignable to type '(...a: A) => B'.
  Type 'B & Function' is not assignable to type '(...a: A) => B'.
    Type 'Function' provides no match for the signature '(...a: A): B'.

360     return value;
```

so I tried to [`Exclude`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#excludeuniontype-excludedmembers) that case

```
function wrapInFunction<A extends Array<unknown>, B>(value: Exclude<B, Function> | ((...a: A) => B)): (...a: A) => B {
  if (typeof value === 'function') {
    return value;
  } else {
    return () => value;
  }
}
```

but I still get

```
src/op.ts:360:5 - error TS2322: Type '((...a: A) => B) | (Exclude<B, Function> & Function)' is not assignable to type '(...a: A) => B'.
  Type 'Exclude<B, Function> & Function' is not assignable to type '(...a: A) => B'.
    Type 'Function' provides no match for the signature '(...a: A): B'.

360     return value;
```

Now, to me, it seems that `Exclude<B, Function> & Function` is an empty type, so if I could prove that that case is impossible to Typescript, then I think my signature would work.

Can I prove `Exclude<B, Function> & Function` is empty? Or is there a better type signature for my `wrapInFunction` function that would accurately represent it?

*Side Note:* When I call this function in my program, I will be calling it with `B` instantiated to things that are obviously not functions, like class types and primitives such as `number`. So, for any use case I care about right now, `Exclude<B, Function>` and `B` should have the same members. But it would be nice to demonstrate that this works in general to the type checker without resorting to good ol' `value as (...a: A) => B` casting.

Comment: The compiler isn't incredibly clever about this, and also `Exclude<unknown, Function>` is just `unknown`, because `Exclude` filters unions.  TS lacks negated types, so you can't write `B extends not Function`.  The closest you can get is something like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mxBDzw) where you represent "not a function" as a union of a bunch of things that the compiler is sure aren't functions.  An object type like `{call?: never}` is not a function, and hopefully you won't worry about passing in `{call: 123}` or something.  Anyway, let me know if you want me to write this up as answer.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you?

```
type S<B> = B extends Function? B : () => B ;

function wrapInFunction<B>(value: B): S<B> {
  return (typeof value === 'function'? value : () => value) as S<B>;
}

wrapInFunction(123);
```